# How to convert characteristic date time into numberic ones in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a column called month as

| month |
| --- |
| JAN |
| FEB |
| ... |
| DEC |

I'd like to know how to convert them into 1,2,3,...,12 in SAS. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use informat to convert it to number and use `month()` to get the month.

```
data have;
    input month :$3. @@;
    datalines;
JAN FEB DEC
;

data want;
  set have;
  x=month(input(month||'21',??monyy.));
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the month with a year, make use of the `MONYY.` informat, use the `MONTH.` format and finally output as a numeric value using another `input()`.

```
data have;
    input month :$3. @@;
    datalines;
JAN FEB DEC
;

data want;
    set have;
    month_num=input(put(input(catt(month, year(today())), monyy.), month.), 2.);
    put month month_num;
run;

Results:  
JAN 1
FEB 2
DEC 12
```